# Sort posts by popularity/page views

Tags: posts, order

How can I sort posts by popularity or page views in my template file?
I guess I need to count page views first, is there any good plugin to integrate with to sort posts by views or what is the best practice of doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The WP Postviews plugin is one of the most used [to record post views](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/).

Then you can sort by amount by;

```
<?php if (function_exists('get_most_viewed')): ?>
<ul>
    <?php get_most_viewed(); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or pass in the variables to the URL:

> ```
> http://example.com/?v_sortby=views&amp;v_orderby=desc
> ```

Or even run a custom query that sorts by the post_meta value.